# Iterating over list element to get specific data

Tags: python

I have following data which is a part of gedcom file (family tree data file)

```
0 @I4@ INDI
1 NAME Milo /Vettle/
2 GIVN Milo
2 SURN Vettle
2 _MARNM Vettle
1 SEX M
1 BIRT
2 DATE 23 OCT 1930
1 FAMS @F3@
0 @I5@ INDI
1 NAME Rosy /Huleknberg/
2 GIVN Rosy
2 SURN Huleknberg
2 _MARNM Vettle
1 SEX F
1 BIRT
2 DATE 15 SEP 1928
1 DEAT Y
2 DATE 10 MAR 2010
```

in above data 1st number is level number next is tag and following tag is argument. i saved this data in list. Now, I want to search for 'BIRT' tag and when program hits that i want to print its next line which is a birth date. If you notice closely there is one more date by 'DEAT' tag but i want date followed by 'BIRT' tag only.

How can i accomplish this task? 
I tried

```
  for line in list:
     if 'BIRT' in line:
        if 'DATE' in line:

          print line
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you've tried

Comment: As @cricket_007 has pointed out, please edit your question to include what you've tried, in what form do you have this data? List? File?

Comment: is there any other editing required ?

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/madprime/python-gedcom which is a python library for handling GEDCOM files as a source of some additional parsing ideas if you go further with this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THanks for editing the question with sample code. Here is a solution that sets a trigger when encountering 'BIRT' in a line, and only if set, outputs a line with 'DATE' in it. Note, if you would also only want lines with 'DATE' in it **directly** following the 'BIRT' line, you have to modify the code a bit ;-)

Code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function

d = """
0 @I4@ INDI
1 NAME Milo /Vettle/
2 GIVN Milo
2 SURN Vettle
2 _MARNM Vettle
1 SEX M
1 BIRT
2 DATE 23 OCT 1930
1 FAMS @F3@
0 @I5@ INDI
1 NAME Rosy /Huleknberg/
2 GIVN Rosy
2 SURN Huleknberg
2 _MARNM Vettle
1 SEX F
1 BIRT
2 DATE 15 SEP 1928
1 DEAT Y
2 DATE 10 MAR 2010
"""

trigger_found = False
token_trigger = 'BIRT'
token_grep = 'DATE'

for line in d.split('\n'):
    if token_trigger in line:
        trigger_found = True
        continue
    if trigger_found and token_grep in line:
        print(line)
        trigger_found = False
```

Test run with Python v2.7.11:

```
2 DATE 23 OCT 1930
2 DATE 15 SEP 1928
```

Same with python v3.

Note: It might also be more robust (given your input as olny sample), to trigger on a token like `BIRT` (padded with spaces, as the text given in the sample looks like there could be textfields that might have been "entered" containing the "code") as say:

```
2 GIVN BIRTE
```

which is a valid given name. That would not change the output in this sample case, but it would set the "trigger" unintendedly.

**Update** (answering a question in comment):

This line in above snippet:

```
for line in d.split('\n'):
```

creates a list out of the textblock stoerd in `d`by splitting on newlines.

If you already have a list of lines in a list `foo`, say because of reading from a file or otherwise, you can instead write:

```
for line in foo:
```

When reading from a file you often have the newline chacter included in the "line" thus you often see `s_line = line.strip()` short after the for ... loop header to get rid of that one and any white space surrounding the "wanted stuff from that line". HTH

**Update**: Good catch from OP. There was a typo in the answer, it was written:

```
if token_trigger and token_grep in line:
```

instead of the correct:

```
if trigger_found and token_grep in line:
```

That way, resetting the trigger to `False` after successful print of the wanted BIRTH DATE was useless.

Comment: what is this type d = " " "......... " " ". Can i use the same with list ?

Comment: Ah yes of course, sorry. In python you have the triple quoted strings that allow you to carry multiline text without the tricks of ijecting the `\n` chacter escape. I often use it as trick to have a complete showcase. I will update the answer. THanks for the feedback.

Comment: i want solution which can read through list and complete the task. Your solution is reading date related to death also ( which i dont want). I am kind of new to this language and still learning hence facing such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Following is something I came up in one shot, its not pretty and elegant but you can use it as reference to build on your own solution

```
def test():

    text = '''  0 @I4@ INDI
                1 NAME Milo /Vettle/
                2 GIVN Milo
                2 SURN Vettle
                2 _MARNM Vettle
                1 SEX M
                1 BIRT
                2 DATE 23 OCT 1930
                1 FAMS @F3@
                0 @I5@ INDI
                1 NAME Rosy /Huleknberg/
                2 GIVN Rosy
                2 SURN Huleknberg
                2 _MARNM Vettle
                1 SEX F
                1 BIRT
                2 DATE 15 SEP 1928
                1 DEAT Y
                2 DATE 10 MAR 2010'''
    lines = text.split('\n')

    tokens = [l.split(' ') for l in lines]

    tags = [token[1] for token in tokens]
    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(tags) if x == 'BIRT']

    for i in indices:
        if tags[i+1] == 'DATE':
            print(lines[i+1])
```

**Output:**

```
        2 DATE 23 OCT 1930
        2 DATE 15 SEP 1928
```

**PS:** the line `tokens = [l.split(' ') for l in lines]` is by assumption that space is separator. If its not the case in reality you can change it

**Update**:

Given that you are reading data from the file you can replace

```
lines = text.spilt('\n')
```

with

```
file = open('path_to_file')
lines = file.readlines()
```

and then continue with the same code in solution

Comment: That is the sample data you provided, I just assigned it to variable for my convenience. You can read it off the file.

Comment: i got no output now! I am kind of new to this language and hence facing such problems

Answer (score 0):

Use [`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

```
$ grep -A1 '1 BIRT' so.txt | grep -E '^2'
2 DATE 23 OCT 1930
2 DATE 15 SEP 1928
```